# How can set the fix height to SMART_BANNER

Tags: android, xml, admob

How can I set the fix height to SMART_BANNER. I'm trying every way to do that and I read the following documentation:

[BANNER](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner) ,
[AdSize](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize)

But it is not working. I'm trying to edit `adView.class` but it's not enable to rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the size of the ad banner a smart banner, use this code:

```
bannerAd.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
```

Then replace the `bannerAd` with your banner ad's name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can set the height to '32dp' allows ?

Comment: I edited it actually I don't know why but I had it setting the size to a banner, but I changed it to `SMART_BANNER`. The Smart Banner detects the screen size and based off of that, it will either set the size to 32dp, 50dp, or 90dp. So it is automatic

Comment: I'm trying to get a new size or resize when the screen mode change from a portrait  to landscape.

Comment: try this [link](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob/issues/79)